# Android Generate Signed APK : keytool error: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format

Tags: java, android, jks

We have already spent past week debugging this problem. We have a live android app in the Google Play Store and have pushed a few updates to it already in the past successfully. There has been no changes in the .jks file that we have been using and we have followed the exact same procedure since starting. We are trying to generate the signed APK using Android Studio so we can push updates to production. When we do that, specifying the keystore path, passwords and alias name, it results in following error and we are stuck:

```
java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
```

Even when I tried to run the below keytool command, I got the same error.

```
keytool -list -keystore <our_keystore>.jks
```

**Backup strategy for our jks**

We had backups of .jks file renaming the same file as 
_01.jks
_02.jks and so on. We had this backup on our own lynux machine for security reasons and we didn't back this up somewhere like bitbucket.

**This is what we have done so far:**

1. We have copied the .jks file into different machines and tried executing the above keytool command, but it gives us the same error.
2. Downloaded this [keytool explorer](http://keystore-explorer.org/) tool and tried to analyze our backups one by one listed above but a couple of backups gave us the message [image] and a couple others gave us the message (After it asked to enter the password and we did) - [image]

As mentioned earlier, we have not played with the jks files and have pushed updates in the past as normal. We are frightened to even imagine that we will have to re-publish our app as we have live users using this application. Now all our hope is on this community. Can anyone please help us as to what we should do and what might have happened?

Comment: Can you read the backup versions? If so, use the latest one you can read.

Comment: @EJP what do you mean by "read the backup versions"? When I used the keytool explorer, I am getting the errors as shown in the images I attached.

Comment: You said you had several backups of the file. Can you read *any* of them? It isn't clear from your post. You've only said a couple did this, a couple did that, ...

Comment: @EJP sorry if it wasn't clear. Yes I tried all that and couldn't read any. All of them resulted in some error or the other.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error, I also used to get this error, only think s you need to install java or update it, after that, the terminal code will work. At least, that worked for me.